# Apache2 Virtual Hosting ServerName in Ubuntu Server 14.04 in LAN not Working

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I have a Apache2 in my Ubuntu Server (14.04) in my home installed. 
I tried to visit this Apache Server in my LAN environment. (Server IP is static: `192.168.0.105`).

My Problem is: if I enter `192.168.0.105` in my laptop, I can visit the Apache2, but if I write my Apache ServerName (`www.pigeontest.de`), it will not work.

These were the steps I followed so far:

1. I set "Server Name" under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/pigeontest.de.conf` already like below (or in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kb8F.png)):

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
             ServerAdmin webmaster@ubuntu.lan

             ServerName www.pigeontest.de
             ServerAlias pigeontest.de

             DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pigeontest.de
        <Directory "/var/www/html/pigeontest.de">
             Options Indexes  
             DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
             AllowOverride All
             Order allow,deny
             Allow from all
           Require all granted 
         </Directory> 

             ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pigeontest.de/error.log
             CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pigeontest.de/access.log combined

   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. Then I did:

   ```
   sudo a2ensite pigeontest.de.conf
   ```
3. Then I edit `/etc/hosts` to:

   ```
   127.0.0.1       localhost  
   127.0.1.1       UbuntuServer www.pigeontest.de

   # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
   ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
   ```
4. Then

   ```
   sudo service apache2 reload
   ```
5. Then

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

It still does not work though. How can I access my site using its server name/domain name?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a domain name related issue.

Are you sure you set your domain name provider's nameserver settings to point to the hosting provider's domain servers?

For example, assume you use digitalocean for hosting, you need to go to the control panel of domain name registrar, find fields named "Domain Name Server" and set their values to 'ns1.digitalocean.com', 'ns2.digitalocean.com' and 'ns3.digitalocean.com'.

Also, you can verify if you did it successfully by whois.

p.s.: It may take an hour or two for the changes to be reflected on your site.